# change key to col and value to values php

Tags: php, arrays

The array is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [dnu] => 121428 [d1] => 43 [d3] => 27 [d7] => 20 [d15] => 15 [d30] => 12 ) )
```

i want something like this:

```
[{"col":"dnu","value":121428},{"col":"d1","value":"43"},{"col":"d7","value":"20"}]
```

Comment: You should loop array with json_encode.

Comment: $p = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);          foreach ($p as $key => $value) {
    $data['col'] = $key;
    $data['value'] = $value;
    
  } echo json_encode($data);  //output  : {"col":"d30","value":"12"} .    it only give last array value it override the same variable ($data) . How could i get proper all value ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$result = [];
foreach($array as $col => $value) {
    $result[] = [
         'col' => $col,
         'value' => $value
    ];
}

$json = json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Mark it as answered then :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way with `foreach()` and `json_encode()`

```
<?php
$array = array ( array ( 'dnu' => 121428, 'd1' => 43, 'd3' => 27, 'd7' => 20, 'd15' => 15, 'd30' => 12 ) );
$result = [];
foreach($array[0] as $key=>$value){
    $result[] = ['col'=>$key,'value'=>$value];
}

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/vfG9k